# How to form one string array based on two other arrays using map in ES5?

Tags: javascript, es5-shim

I am writing a simple js/es5 script to combine all the strings in a CWL. The CWL only supports ES5, so there are many functions/features from ES6 cannot be used. I am not familiar with js in general.

For a minimal example:

```
var arr1 = ["a", "b"]
var arr2 = ["111", "222"]
```

Expected result:

```js
["a_111", "b_111", "a_222", "b_222"] // order doesn't matter
```

I tried this way, but it did not work and only returned ["a_111", "b_111"]

```
arr1.map(function(x) {
  return arr2.map(function(y) {
    return x + "_" + y;
  });
});
```

Comment: What is a CWL? I'm assuming it doesn't stand for "Catholic Women's League".

Comment: haha, it is "common workflow language"

Comment: you must return in the first map also. then need to flat. using flatMap couldve been much easier but i think cant in es5

Comment: my bad flat() is also not es5 it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother using `map` for this. Just have a nested loop and push a string into a new array.

```js
var arr1 = ['a', 'b'];
var arr2 = ['111', '222'];

var out = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    var str = arr1[j] + '_' + arr2[i];
    out.push(str);
  }
}

console.log(out);
```

Comment: ah, totally forget the for loop. Thank you! I think i will use for loop for now. Everyone feels free to post answer if there is a more convenient way.

Comment: Half-the problem is that no-one really caters for ES5 anymore. I had to edit my code after I realised you can't use `const` or template strings :) @WenliL Hope the coding goes well.

Answer (score 1):

What you can use is a combination of `reduce()`, `concat()` and `map()`:

```js
let result = arr1.reduce((acc, a) => acc.concat(arr2.map((b) => a + "_" + b)), []);
// => [ 'a_111', 'a_222', 'b_111', 'b_222' ]
```

Alternatively when `flat()` is available you can use:

```js
let result = arr1.map((a) => arr2.map((b) => a + "_" + b)).flat();
// => [ 'a_111', 'a_222', 'b_111', 'b_222' ]
```

I am not sure if `flat()` works with ES5 though.